# What does mean the parameter %0.2f% with two percents symbols in printf

Tags: shell, printf

I'm working with one file.sh, but I didn't understood what does two percent symbols means `%0.2f%`.

The command read a value in tmp.err and print it, just this, look below:

```
awk '{ printf("*** Error: %0.2f%\n",substr($2, 2, length($2) - 2) * 100) }' tmp.err
```

The file *tmp.err* have this two values separated by white space `11736 (0.17908)`.

I already know `%0.2f` means a float value with two decimals.

someone know what does `%0.2f%` do? or is a typo?

I'm asking this question, because right now I'm receiving an error,  *not enough arguments passed to printf(* bu if I remove the last percentage like this `%0.2f` works fine.

thanks

Comment: Looks like a typo to me.

Comment: maybe yes, what I think strange this command works fine inside other app I did download.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that the argument is multiplied by 100 leads me to think that whoever wrote that intended for a literal percent sign, which needs to be doubled.

```
awk '{ printf("*** Error: %0.2f%%\n",substr($2, 2, length($2) - 2) * 100) }' tmp.err
```